# An expression of a check constraint 'producto_chk_3' contains disallowed function: now

Tags: mysql, sql

El error aparece cuando quiero poner la restricción de que las fechas que se registren en esta tabla sean mayores o igual a la fecha actual, esto trato de hacerlo con la función `NOW()`, y ya he intentado también con `DATE(NOW())`, `CURDATE()`, pero todas me lanzan error, el código con el que intento crear la tabla es.

```
CREATE TABLE producto(id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
categoria_id int,
nombre varchar(20),
desc_corta varchar(10) DEFAULT 'Medicament',
descripcion varchar(40) DEFAULT 'Medicamento Generico',
precio float CHECK(precio > 0),
stock int NOT NULL CHECK(stock > 0),
fecha date CHECK (fecha > DATE(now())),
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY (categoria_id) REFERENCES categoria(id)
);
```

El error en efecto es:

> (HY000): An expression of a check constraint 'producto_chk_3' contains disallowed function: now

Uso MySQL 8.0

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar mejor lo que buscas lograr?, igual y esos check tal vez no hagan falta

Comment: Si es añadir una condición de que las fechas que se ingresen a la base de datos sean mayores o igual a la fecha actual, que según la documentación se puede obtener con NOW()

Comment: Sería mucho mas simple con trigger before INSERT que tome el valor new y con un condicional evalúe si es mayor o no y actúe en consecuencia

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, pero necesito saber si es problema de mi instalación, o si el código es incorrecto, ya que he usado CHECK en otras condiciones y ejecuta de manera correcta.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que la tarea que quieres realizar (*la evaluación*) sería mas conveniente en asignarla a un trigger de esta forma:

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE TRIGGER evaluaFecha BEFORE INSERT ON tuTabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.fecha < NOW() THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'La fecha ingresada no es válida';
    END IF;
END;
//
```

Lo que hacemos es:

- Crear un trigger *que actúe* antes de la inserción de la nueva fila
- Evalúe el valor que esta por ser ingresado mismo al que accedemos por medio de `NEW.campo`
- Con un condicional construimos una condición donde revisamos si la fecha nueva es menor a la actual entonces notificamos con un mensaje de error, en caso contrario dejamos que la inserción continúe su camino.

Por otro lado, el tema esta en la función que usas en el `check` pues como puedes observar en la documentación y cito<sup>1</sup>:

> Literals, deterministic built-in
> functions, and operators are permitted. A function is deterministic
> if, given the same data in tables, multiple invocations produce the
> same result, independently of the connected user. Examples of
> functions that are nondeterministic and fail this definition:
> CONNECTION_ID(), CURRENT_USER(), NOW().

Que se puede traducir como:

> Se permiten literales, funciones integradas deterministas y
> operadores. Una función es determinista si, dados los mismos datos en
> tablas, múltiples invocaciones producen el mismo resultado,
> independientemente del usuario conectado. Ejemplos de funciones que no
> son deterministas y fallan en esta definición: CONNECTION_ID (),
> CURRENT_USER (), NOW ().

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [*CHECK constraints*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)
- [Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar la función now() en las restricciones check, no permite funciones no deterministicas. Chequea la [documentacion de MySql 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html).